# Link in address bar goes back to the folder in php for IE browser

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php mysql website. It is working fine with chrome and opera browsers.

But when I work in Internet Explorer, the php page is not working.

I have a login page

localhost/abc/login.php

When I submit the login page form, the link in address bar goes back to

localhost/abc/

with a 404 browser error. However, everything if fine with Chrome and Opera browsers. There are some other threads also, but not suffice for me.

Could anyone suggest if I need to add any extra lines of html tags on php pages ?

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>

<title> Login Page </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward();
function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">

<?php
session_start();
$show_form=true;
$MerrorMessage = "";
$PerrorMessage = "";
$MailformaterrorMessage="";
$MailIdPwderrorMessage="";

if(!isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$_POST['MailId']="";
$_POST['Password']=""; 
}


if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
sleep( 2 );

    $path6 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path6 .= "/CMP/passwordLib.php";
    include_once($path6);

    $path7 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path7 .= "/CMP/passwordLibClass.php";
    include_once($path7);

$MailId=$_POST['MailId']; 
$Password=$_POST['Password']; 

    if (empty($_POST['MailId']) || !preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $MailId) || empty($_POST['Password']))
        {

      if(empty($_POST['MailId'])) 
        {
          $MerrorMessage = "You forgot to enter a MailId!";
        }

      else if(!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $MailId))
        {
          $MailformaterrorMessage = "Email ID format is not correct!";
        }

      if(empty($_POST['Password'])) 
        {
          $PerrorMessage = "You forgot to enter a Password!";
        }
         }

      else
        {
          $path1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
              $path1 .= "/cmp/Connection.php";
          include_once($path1);
              $tbl_name="cmp_usertable";

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
              $MailId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$MailId);
          $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Password);
          $MailId=strip_tags($MailId);
              $Password=strip_tags($Password);

          $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Email='$MailId' ";
          $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

          $Status=$row['AccountStatus'];
          $UserId=$row['Userid'];
          $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
          $LastName=$row['LastName'];
          $Gender=$row['Gender'];
          $hash=$row['Password'];
              $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);



// If result matched $MailId , table row must be 1 row
          if($count==1)
        {

           if (password_verify($Password, $hash))
           {

            $_SESSION['$MailId'] = $_POST['MailId'];
            $_SESSION['UserId'] = $UserId;
            $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $FirstName;
            $_SESSION['LastName'] = $LastName;
            $_SESSION['Gender'] = $Gender;

            if ($Status=='A')
                {

// Register $MailId, $Password and redirect to file "Home.php"
                    header("location:Home.php");
                }


            else if ($Status=='P')
                {

                    header("location:FirstLogin.php");
                    echo "First Time Login";
                }
            else if ($Status=='D')
                {

                    header("location:Deactivated.php");
                }
                }

            else
            {
            $MailIdPwderrorMessage="Invalid Email or Password";
            }
        }

           else {
            $MailIdPwderrorMessage="Invalid Email or Password";

                }


          }

}


if(true == $show_form)
{
?>

<table width="900" border="3"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#006666">


<tr height="500">
<td width="700" align="center"><font color="FFFFFF" size="5" face="Biondi"> My website </br>
</font> 
</td>

<form name="form1" method="post" action=" ">
<td width="300" rowspan="2">
<table  width="70%" border="2" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#006666">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong><font color="FFFFFF">Member Login</font> </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="78"><font color="FFFFFF">MailId</font></td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="MailId" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['MailId'] ?>" id="MailId" maxlength="60">
<span class="isa_error"><?php echo "<FONT color='RED'> $MerrorMessage </font>"?></span>
<span class="isa_error"><?php echo "<FONT color='RED'> $MailformaterrorMessage </font>"?></span>

</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><font color="FFFFFF">Password</font></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="Password" type="Password" id="Password" maxlength="30">
<span class="isa_error"><?php echo "<FONT color='RED'> $PerrorMessage </font>" ?></span>
<span class="isa_error"><?php echo "<FONT color='RED'> $MailIdPwderrorMessage </font>"?></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" style="width: 100px;"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</form>


</tr>


</table>
<?PHP
}//true == $show_form
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can u provide your form code for refer the code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$show_form=true;
if(!isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
...
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
....
}


if(true == $show_form)
{
?>

<table width="900" border="3"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#006666">
<tr height="500">
<td width="700" align="center"><font color="FFFFFF" size="5" face="Biondi"> My website </br>
</font> 
</td>
<form name="form1" method="post" action=" ">

...........form goes here......

</form>
</tr>
</table>
<?PHP
}//true == $show_form
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please see it in a notepad...cant paste more than this....

Comment: Is this your login.php page?

Comment: yes...there was character limits, so I cant paste whole page content here...

Comment: edit you question with the code in your page

Comment: Thanks. Question edited with login page... Please suggest. Its working fine with Chrome but not with IE